# How to read SendReplyToReceive parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

i am working on a Web Application using Asp .net and Workflow Foundation 4. I hanve a Workflow service which has a Receive message activity and a `SendReplyToReceive`. I have defined a parameter in the `SendReplyToReceive` which I am assigning in its value a string. How can I read this parameter when I call the workflow service?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll create a workflow variable, and assign the value of the parameter to the variable in the "Assign To" field in the Content Definition dialog. You can then access the variable in the workflow.